# select group by rows that follow some attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an
 artists table `id, name`
 bands table `id, name, genre`
 band-artist table `artistid, bandid`
And I'm trying to query all the artists that don't preform in a rock band (an artist can play in more than one band.
The following query works:

```
SELECT  a.name  
FROM     arIst  a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(SELECT  *  
     FROM    arIst  a,  bandMembers bm, band    b   
     WHERE      a.id    =   bm.arIstID  
         AND    bm.id   =   b.id
         AND    b.genre =   “rock");
```

But I'm trying to achieve it with group by:

```
select a.name
from artists a, band b, band-artist ba
where a.id=ba.artistid and b.id=ba.bandid
group by(a.id)
HAVING ??? <--- here I am stuck
```

How can I show only the group by groups, that all the rows in the group follow certain rule?
 Here it's `band.genre != 'rock'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a `left join`, because some artists may not be in *any* bands.  Second, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.

```
select a.id, a.name  -- in case two artists have the same name
from artists a left join
     band_artist ba
     on a.id = ba.artistid left join
     band b
     on b.id = ba.bandid
group by a.id, a.name
having sum(band.genre = 'rock') = 0;  -- the number of rock bands is 0
```

Comment: That's awesome. whats the downside of not using the standard join?

Comment: @DsCpp It tends to lead to downvotes. More seriously, different types of join have different join precedence. When you start to mix these things up, it can lead to unexpected results. Standard joins also aid readability - especially in more complex queries.

Comment: Also, using standard join syntax, your `JOIN` conditions are separate from your `WHERE` conditions, which can clarify your query's intentions.